# How to archive org mode TODO entry if all the child TODOs are done?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Current org file

```
* TODO test
** TODO test 1
** TODO test 2
** DONE test 3

* DONE test 4
** DONE test 5
```

The expected output to current file

```
* TODO test
** TODO test 1
** TODO test 2
** DONE test 3
```

Archive file

```
* DONE test 4
** DONE test 5
```

I used the agenda mode way to archive, ie C-c a t N r (mark items) B $
but that moved the item `** DONE test 3` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative technique to achieve similar results.

```
C-^ O // order by todo order
C-c $ // archive
C-x z // repeat previous command
z // repeat
z
z
```